# Design a Jig and Fixture for 3-axis CNC Milling Machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, mechanical, cnc, machine-design

Newbie Here!!!

This is my assignment task. I am required to design a Jig and Fixture for 3-axis CNC Milling Machine. The workpiece will be a simple aluminium block and it will be cut and shaped into a flywheel.

I had searched online about Jig and Fixture. Most of them stated that jig is used for guiding the cutting tool for operation such as drilling, reaming, tapping and boring operation. The Fixture is used to hold and support your workpiece.

The question is.....

1. Why do I need Jig to guide the cutting tool for a simple drilling operation? Can't a 3-axis CNC Milling Machine perform the drilling process automatically itself?
2. Is Jig actually placed on the workpiece or milling table instead of getting clamped to the milling table? (I google searched, I saw some mentioned that Jig is not clamped to the table!!) Is it true, won't the Jig get moved during the cutting process?
3. What else can I use the Jig for in my assignment?

Comment: The problem you've had is "Jig" is a more general term for an 'alignment thing'. In CNC, it would be used for lining up the stock material quickly and easily into the correct position. For example, once you've machined one half of the flywheel, and want to flip it over to machine the other half - how would you align it? Use a Jig!

Comment: Yes the jig or fixture (which are synonymous in this case) are used to hold a piece of stock you’d want to make dozens or hundreds of times in the same position without having to find the workpiece zero coordinate (a cnc is only as smart as what it knows...if it doesn’t know where the workpiece is each time, it can’t do anything) with the jig you always know where it is in the machine and you can just rerun the gcode over and over again